# how to create copy constructor when the class contains a pointer

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a problem with copy constructor concept. I wrote an example like this:

```
struct f1
{
     string x;
     string y;
     f1();
     ~f1();
};
struct f2
{
    int a;
    string b;
    f1 *ff;
    f2();
    ~f2();
};
class myclass{
    f2 *obj;
}
```

I found that struct f2 should have a copy constructor since the class contains a pointer to allocated memory. but I don't know how I should create it.

Comment: Depending on use-case you could use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and use [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Comment: There's no simple answer. It really depends on who owns the object pointed to by `f2`.

Comment: And on what it represents.

Comment: Your alternative is *deep copy* (copy what is pointed to) vs *shallow copy* (just duplicate the pointer).

Comment: Not only a copy constructor but an copy assigment operator too. But really this question cannot be answered unless you explain what you expect to happen. Specifically after a copy will the original and the copy share the allocated memory or will they each have their own copy?

Comment: @john actually cppcheck shows this error. I added the class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options:

Main two:

1. Just copy the pointer (shallow copying), just without writing the constructor, it will be implicit, or you could write (in the `struct f2`).

   ```
   f2(const f2 &original): f1(original.f1), a(original.a), b(original.b) { }
   ```

> ***WARNING:*** This will **NOT** copy the value of `f1` member variable. It will just copy the reference, this makes both `f2.f1` s **refer** to same `f1` object.
>
> ```
> f2 a;
> ...
> f2 b(a); // Invokes the "copy" constructor
> a.f1->x = "Something here";
> std::cout << b.f1->x; // Will print "Something here"
> ```

2. Make a deep copy, you invoke the copy constructor of `f1`, and assign the newly created copy to `this->f1` by writing this into `struct f2`

   ```
   f2(const f2 &original): f1(new f1(*original.f1)), a(original.a), b(original.b) { }
   ```

   Also as one commenter suggests, that you **MUST** also make a copy assignment because you made a copy constructor (except if your object is immutable for example)

   ```
   f2 &operator=(const f2 &other) {
       if (this == &other) return; // If "self-assignment" just return.

       if (f1) { delete f1; } // Deletes the old one if any.
                              // The advisable alternative is to use
                              //    a smart pointer
       f1 = new f1(*other.f1);
       a = other.a;
       b = other.b;
       return *this;
   }
   ```

Anyway, you should consider using *smart pointers*: `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`, because raw pointers may cause a lot of errors. But smart pointers manage the memory (partially) for you, giving you more opportunity to think about your logic. Some modern C++ programmers say that you should seldom use `delete`, smart pointers will do the work

Comment: Can't really agree with this answer. Suggestion 1 doesn't work because f1 is dynamically allocated. Also in suggestion 2 the implementation of assignment operator is bugged in the case of assignment to self.

Comment: @john Fixing assignment to self, thanks. But why suggestion 1 doesn't work?, I think it will do a "shallow copy", just copy the reference. (Except if he needs a "deep copy").

Comment: @john Tried to improve the answer, you can check it now

Comment: Because once the pointer is copied and both objects have the same pointer there is no way to know when to delete the pointer. If the destructor does delete the pointer then you will delete the same pointer twice and if it doesn't you have a memory leak.

Comment: @john And this is why he is advised to use smart pointers, this "shared raw pointers" are very error prone, but he "may" have a project requirement that for example, this `f1` is managed by other parent object, like a document model that contains a group of all this, that "owns" all those objects. But using smart pointers or immutability/copying may be a better idea.

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty much a normal constructor that takes an instance of its own type as an argument

```
f2(const f2& other):a(other.a),b(other.b),ff(new f1()){
    memcpy(ff,other.ff,sizeof(f1));//makes copy of ff
}
```

Comment: you cannot do `strcpy` on `std::string` and you cannot do `memcpy` on an object that is not trivially copyable. Your code is very very wrong.

Comment: Ok, fixed string copy. Did not know assignment of std::string is already a deep copy. I didn't worry about deep copying f1 because the question was just about making a copy constructor for f2.

Comment: Just ff(new f1(*other.ff)) then? I wanted to avoid just using implicit copy constructors when the question also was about them.